# How do I explicitly set an svn password when checking out a repository from the command line

Tags: svn, command-line, passwords

I'm getting *svn: Authorization failed* error and I want to make sure that I typed the correct password the first time, so I want to reset the password.

When I try to check out the repository there's no longer a prompt for a password after the password was typed the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command line help :)

```
svn help co
```

There you can see:

```
Global options:
  --username ARG           : specify a username ARG
  --password ARG           : specify a password ARG
```

If you want that svn client forgets your password you must delete the appropiate file in `~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/`